# How to ignore beginning spaces in sed during replace?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I want to ignore the beginning spaces in a file during pattern search and replacement. The final output doesn't need to have spaces. I have to match the whole line and replace with desired line. Tried different ways but the replacement is not happening as the white spaces are not matching.

**Input file.txt:**

```
Access /var/tmp/access.log  
    LogFormat "%h \"%r\" %>s %b\" common  
Error /var/tmp/err.log
```

**Expected file.txt:**

```
Access /var/tmp/access.log  
    LogFormat "%T %h \"%r\" %>s %b" common    
Error /var/tmp/error.log
```

The below is what I tried and none works. The file remains same.

```
source1="LogFormat \"%h \\"%r\\" %>s %b\" common"
destination1="LogFormat \"%T %h \\"%r\\" %>s %b\" common"
sed -i "s|$source1|$destination1|" file.txt
sed -i "s|^(\s*)$source1|$destination1|" file.txt
sed -i "s|^\s*$source1|$destination1|" file.txt
sed -i "s|^[[:blank:]]$source1|$destination1|" file.txt
sed -i "s|^[[:blank:]]*$source1|$destination1|" file.txt
```

Please let me know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[[::blank::]]` lacks a quantifier so it's taken as just one space.

Comment: @pLumo Tried that too. It didn't work. I just updated the question with the command I tried.

Comment: I escaped the required chars and the variable looks OK. Sorry, I'm new to this site and unable to write comments in a clear format.

 # printf '%s\n' "$source1"

LogFormat "%h \%r\ %>s %b" common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to double escape you `source1` variable and use single quotes:

```bsh
$ source1='LogFormat \\\"%h \\\\"%r\\\\" %>s %b\\\" common'
$ sed "s|$source1|$destination1|" file
Access /var/tmp/access.log  
    LogFormat "%T %h \"%r\" %>s %b" common  
Error /var/tmp/err.log
```

With the `\s` (in GNU `sed`):

```bsh
$ sed "s|^\s*$source1|$destination1|" file 
Access /var/tmp/access.log  
LogFormat "%T %h \"%r\" %>s %b" common
Error /var/tmp/err.log
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you both.